# By clicking AddRoom i want to attach the same dialog which is i displayed previously. is there any chance to display nested dialog using fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

By clicking Add Room i want to attach the same dialog which is i displayed previously. is there any chance to display nested dialog using fragments.

```
AddRoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           final FragmentManager fm=getChildFragmentManager();
            Room_Selection_Dialog_Fragment RSDF=new Room_Selection_Dialog_Fragment();


            if(fm!=null)
            {
                AddRoom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Done.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                cancel_action.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.buttonslayout,RSDF);

                RSDF.Done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        int fadultvalue,fchildvalue,froomval;
                        froomval=gfv.getFinalnoofrooms();
                        fadultvalue=gfv.getFinalnoofadultscount();
                        fchildvalue=gfv.getFinalnoofchildcount();
                        donelistener.OnFinishRequiredRooms(froomval,fadultvalue,fchildvalue);
                        getDialog().dismiss();

                    }
                });

                ft.commit();
            }


        }
    });
```